# WHERE clause in SSRS expression

Tags: ssrs-2008, where-clause, ssrs-expression, stackedbarseries

What's the syntax for inserting a `WHERE` clause in an `SSRS expression`? I am using `BIDS 2008`.

```
=Sum(Fields!QuantityToShip.Value) WHERE FIELDS!Program.Value = "FC"
```

The code listed above represents the logic I want to use, but obviously inserting the `WHERE` in there creates a syntax error.

The purpose of this expression is to define a series' value field in a stacked bar chart.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Was my answer of any use?  Did you try it?

Comment: Hi Sir Crispalot - Yes, it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use the [IIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.iif.aspx) method:

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!Program.Value = "FC", Fields!QuantityToShip.Value, 0))
```

Comment: hi, what if i have 2 fields for where clause can i just use like this:  Fields!Program.Value = "FC" and Fields!Program.Value = "GC"

Comment: Well it's just a boolean expression, so you should be able to do something like: `=Sum(IIF((Fields!Program.Value = "FC" And Fields!Program.OtherValue = "XX"), Fields!QuantityToShip.Value, 0))`.  Obviously your example won't work because `Program.Value` can't be **FC** and **GC** at the same time.  Plus it's `And` in VB, not `and`.

Comment: How can you write an IIF depending upon the value of the intersecting column?

Comment: @T3.0 not entirely sure what you mean. Perhaps try asking a new question with an example of your problem and what you've tried so far.