# SSRS Expression with parameter in WHERE clause

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008-r2

In SSRS, I'm trying to calculate the average number of months a client used a program. The programID is the parameter for the whole report. I'm trying to achieve this (not written with real syntax):

```
=Avg(Fields!length_of_stay.Value, 0))/30.0 WHERE programid = @ProgramID
```

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132505/where-clause-in-ssrs-expression) question, I came up the the following code which is producing an incorrect answer. I tested in SSMS to get the actual values to compare to SSRS results.

```
=Avg(IIF(Fields!programid.Value = Parameters!ProgramID.Value, Fields!Length_of_Stay.Value, 0))/30.0
```

The "/30" is used since the value is in days and I need months. I think the issue is using the parameter value chosen; this is my first report trying to calculate expressions with parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Avg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255289.aspx) returns the average of all non-null numeric values. `0` is not null so it gets included in the average, distorting your result for every row with a different PragramId. Try using `Nothing` instead:

```
=Avg(IIF(Fields!programid.Value = Parameters!ProgramID.Value, Fields!Length_of_Stay.Value, Nothing))/30.0
```