# Error when trying to use Where clause in SSRS expression

Tags: reporting-services

This SO link, [WHERE Caluse in SSRS expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132505/where-clause-in-ssrs-expression), verifies that my syntax is correct yet I get this error:

"An error occurred during local report processing.
The definition of the report is invalid.
The Value expression for the text box 'txt1A_EMA' uses an aggregate expression without a scope. A scope is required for all aggregates used outside of a data region unless the report contains exactly one dataset."

My expression:

```
=Sum(IIF((Fields!COU_EMA.Value, "CA_Summary") = 1, (Fields!Amount.Value, "CA_Summary"), 0))
```

There are 3 Datasets in my report. The one I want is "CA_Summary" and the expression above was built with the expression builder.

The field, (Fields!COU_EMA.Value, "CA_Summary"), is a boolean (1 or 0) and I get error either with a 1 or a "true" (no quotes).

I probably could fix it if I knew what the definition of "scope" is. . . maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope is where you want to look in order to get the values you're looking for. It could be a data set, group, etc. In your expression it appears `CA_Summary` is the scope.

I would try modifying the expression a bit. Since you say `COU_EMA` is  bit field, maybe use `TRUE`. This is also assuming the matrix is using the data set `CA_Summary`.

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!COU_EMA.Value = TRUE, Fields!Amount.Value, 0))
```

If your matrix isn't using that data set and it still doesn't work try

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!COU_EMA.Value = TRUE, Fields!Amount.Value, 0),"CA_Summary")
```